# IQueryable ToListAsync complaining about violated constraint when using custom struct

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-2.2

#### Context

I'm trying to write a function to convert an `IQueryable<T>` to a `IQueryable<CustomType<T, K>>` which can then later be converted to `IEnumerable<CustomType<T, K>>` if necessary.

#### Problem

Given:

```cs
public struct CustomType<TModel, TKey>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }
    public TModel Value { get; set; }
}
```

if I write:

```cs
var list = await query
    .Select(selectExpression) // Selects into `CustomType<T, K>`
    .Where(whereExpression)
    .OrderBy(orderByExpression)
    .Select(x => new { Value = x.Value })
    .ToListAsync();
```

where `selectExpression` is a runtime built expression equivalent to:

```cs
x => new CustomType<T, K> { Key = ..., Value = ... }
```

then everything works as expected and the `selectExpression` which is built at runtime is converted to a single SQL expression.

But if at any point I return `CustomType<T, K>`, like in:

```cs
var list = await query
    .Select(selectExpression) // Selects into `CustomType<T, K>`
    .ToListAsync();
```

Then EF Core complains that in some entity tracking function `CustomType<T, K>` violates some constraint `TIn` (why would it try to track a custom type?)

The specific error code is this one (for `CustomType<OtherType, int>`):

```
GraphQL.ExecutionError: GenericArguments[1], 'CustomType`2[OtherType,System.Int32]', on 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[TOut] _TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[TOut], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityTrackingInfo], System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Func`2[TIn,System.Object]])' violates the constraint of type 'TIn'. ---> GraphQL.Conventions.Execution.FieldResolutionException: GenericArguments[1], 'CustomType`2[OtherType,System.Int32]', on 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[TOut] _TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[TOut], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityTrackingInfo], System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Func`2[TIn,System.Object]])' violates the constraint of type 'TIn'. ---> System.ArgumentException: GenericArguments[1], 'Persistence.IQueryableExtensions+OrderedGroupItem`2[OtherType,System.Int32]', on 'System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[TOut] _TrackEntities[TOut,TIn](System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable`1[TOut], Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityTrackingInfo], System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Func`2[TIn,System.Object]])' violates the constraint of type 'TIn'. ---> System.Security.VerificationException: Method Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider._TrackEntities: type argument 'Persistence.IQueryableExtensions+OrderedGroupItem`2[OtherType,System.Int32]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TIn'.
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.GetStubIfNeeded(RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType declaringType, RuntimeType[] methodInstantiation)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeType.ValidateGenericArguments(MemberInfo definition, RuntimeType[] genericArguments, Exception e)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] methodInstantiation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.TrackEntitiesInResults[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateAsyncQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Aggregate.cs:line 118
```

How can I make it work so that `ToListAsync` returns a `CustomType<T, K>` while having LINQ to SQL work (meaning a single SQL expression is built)?

#### What have I tried

I've tried to make `CustomType` a `class`, but then, for some reason, the LINQ to SQL fails at making a single SQL expression for the `selectExpression` due to the custom type being a `class`.

Comment: What's in your "selectExpression" just before the query runs ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier `selectExpression` is a runtime built expression. I can post the entire code if necessary but it's very long. The equivalent expression for `selectExpression` is `x => new CustomType<T, K> { Key = ..., Value = ... }`.

Comment: Ok the second one is select CustomType, what is selected in the first one that works ??

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Same. `selectExpression` in both code snippets is the same expression.

Comment: So you are telling me that just removing this part : .Where(whereExpression)
    .OrderBy(orderByExpression)
    .Select(x => new { Value = x.Value }) Is causing the problem ?

Comment: Specifically removing `.Select(x => new { Value = x.Value })` is causing the problem. I'm pretty sure LINQ to SQL supports converting anonymous read-only types to SQL expressions. It also seem to support custom `struct` types **unless** you try to return them in an `IEnumerable` via `ToListAsync`.

Comment: Can't reproduce. `struct` variant gives me NRE while `class` version works. Hence minimal reproducible example is needed, including the exact EF Core version.

Comment: What do you mean by NRE?

Comment: Null Reference Exception. Somewhere inside EF Core infrastructure code. My test is on EF Core 2.2.4

Comment: @IvanStoev I've added the error that I'm getting.